# In Apigee, how can I access callout response in javascript policy

Tags: apigee, callout

I created a service callout (eg: `myCallout`) which returns its response in a variable (eg: `myCalloutResponse`). How can I access the body of the callout in a javascript policy?
I tried `context.getVariable("myCallout.myCalloutResponse")` and a few others but couldn't get this to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

context.getVariable("myCalloutResponse.content") should give you the payload. Take a look at other variables available on [response object](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference#-a-class-jumplink-name-response-a-response-message-variables) - to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use : JSON.parse(context.getVariable("myCalloutResponse.content"));

[image]